# Objective C: Implementing drawRect

Tags: objective-c, drawrect, setneedsdisplay

I have a very simple project that involves drawing a shape with drawRect, but I don't believe my drawRect function is actually being called.  Here is the code. (Everything else is just the default for a "Single View Application.")

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)aRect{
    NSLog(@"testing...");
    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50, 50);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 120);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 100);
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFillStroke);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Any advice would be terrific—thanks for reading!

Comment: It looks like you have placed the `drawRect:` in a viewcontroller class. Viewcontrollers do not implement `drawRect:`, subclasses of `UIView` do.

Comment: Yep, you only ever have to call `setNeedsDisplay` on `self`.

Comment: OK, thanks! Still learning how to do that, so will keep at it.

Comment: @Paul.s: That comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have placed the `drawRect:` in a `UIViewController` subclass. `UIViewController`'s do not implement `drawRect:`, subclasses of `UIView` do.

You need to create a custom subclass of `UIView` with your implementation of `drawRect:` and then add this to your view hierarchy either as a child of the view controller's `self.view` prpoperty or as the root view itself.